# slow deleting of multiple records in mysql

Tags: mysql, relational-database, innodb

I noticed that on test server deleting multple rows from table takes much time, for example, deleting 100K rows takes about 80-90 seconds. I use innodb engine in mysql. There are not DELETE triggers. The table has now about 23M rows.
The query that takes long is something like:

```
DELETE FROM contacts WHERE list_id = som_list_id
```

Index is added.

```
EXPLAIN SELECT *
FROM contacts
WHERE list_id =118

id  select_type     table   type    possible_keys   key     key_len     ref     rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE  subscribers     ref     FK_list_id  FK_list_id  4   const   1
```

Here is profiling results:

```
    SET PROFILING = 1;
    DELETE FROM contacts WHERE list_id = 118;
    SHOW PROFILE FOR QUERY 1;


Status  Duration    CPU_user    CPU_system  Context_voluntary   Context_involuntary     Block_ops_in    Block_ops_out   Messages_sent   Messages_received   Page_faults_major   Page_faults_minor   Swaps   Source_function     Source_file     Source_line
starting    0.000031    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
checking permissions    0.000004    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    check_access    sql_parse.cc    4895
Opening tables  0.000031    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    open_tables     sql_base.cc     4860
System lock     0.000005    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    mysql_lock_tables   lock.cc     299
init    0.000079    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    mysql_delete    sql_delete.cc   79
updating    94.624119   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    mysql_delete    sql_delete.cc   277
end     0.000007    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    mysql_delete    sql_delete.cc   356
Waiting for query cache lock    0.000003    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    lock    sql_cache.cc    749
end     0.000006    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
query end   0.012509    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    mysql_execute_command   sql_parse.cc    4584
closing tables  0.000018    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    mysql_execute_command   sql_parse.cc    4636
freeing items   0.000038    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    mysql_parse     sql_parse.cc    5817
logging slow query  0.000006    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    log_slow_statement  sql_parse.cc    1581
logging slow query  0.000000    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    log_slow_statement  sql_parse.cc    1590
cleaning up     0.000003    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    dispatch_command    sql_parse.cc    1443
```

I tried to copy contacts to contact1 that doesn't have child tables which contacts has:
Results of profiling are similar:

```
Status  Duration    CPU_user    CPU_system  Context_voluntary   Context_involuntary     Block_ops_in    Block_ops_out   Messages_sent   Messages_received   Page_faults_major   Page_faults_minor   Swaps   Source_function     Source_file     Source_line
starting    0.000028    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
checking permissions    0.000005    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    check_access    sql_parse.cc    4895
Opening tables  0.000035    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    open_tables     sql_base.cc     4860
System lock     0.000014    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    mysql_lock_tables   lock.cc     299
init    0.000792    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    mysql_delete    sql_delete.cc   79
updating    72.805936   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    mysql_delete    sql_delete.cc   277
end     0.000006    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    mysql_delete    sql_delete.cc   356
Waiting for query cache lock    0.000002    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    lock    sql_cache.cc    749
end     0.000006    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
query end   0.013662    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    mysql_execute_command   sql_parse.cc    4584
closing tables  0.000017    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    mysql_execute_command   sql_parse.cc    4636
freeing items   0.000044    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    mysql_parse     sql_parse.cc    5817
logging slow query  0.000003    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    log_slow_statement  sql_parse.cc    1581
logging slow query  0.000002    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    log_slow_statement  sql_parse.cc    1590
cleaning up     0.000003    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    dispatch_command    sql_parse.cc    1443
```

It looks like updating consumes most of the time.

Why does deleting takes so long? Does it take so much time because I/O system of server is slow?
Thank you.

Comment: Your `DELETE` is on a different table to the `EXPLAIN SELECT` and profile... I guess that's just a typo?

Comment: It's the same talble, I corrected.

Comment: The question is why does it take so much time to delet something like 100K rows.

Comment: Do you have any relation with `contacts` table?

Comment: For this 100K rows there not any rows in child table for contancts.

Comment: There is parent table lists to contancts. For contacts tables there are some child tables with foreign constaint as well for storing some additional info. But for deleting rows thare are not any data in child tables.

Comment: Do you have any relation with `contacts` table? If so, it doesn't matter if you don't have child records for the ones you're deleting, engine must search for child rows anyway. Try to *copy* your table (without relations) elsewhere and execute same delete query: how much time does it take?

Comment: I answered your question in previous comments. Yes, contacts table has relation with several tables. I'll try to copy data to table without these relations.

Comment: Also, are there any `DELETE` triggers defined on the table?

Comment: There are not DELETE triggers.

Comment: I added to post info about profiling copy of the table without child tables.

Answer (score 0):

Is the table MyISAM?  If so try the

```
    delete quick from contacts...
```

Followed by

```
    optimize table contacts
```

Using quick does not have the database merge the index during the delete.  Then optimize reclaims unused space defrays the table.

Comment: In my question I wrote that I use innodb.